# Visual Studio : Design Time Error (Item has already been added)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, user-controls, vsto

I'm working on a PowerPoint 2013 add-in project, I added a UserControl to the project and started to fill it with a lot of controls, but recently I moved some files, which caused some problems only in the UserControl.

**The problems I have in the UserControl:**

- When I open the project this error appears: [image: error on opening]
- One of the `TablelayoutPanel`s inside the UserControl, which is named `FormatShapePage2`, is not shown in rightpanel.vb [Design], since its name is duplicated in the dictionary.

**What I have tried**

- I tried to change the name of the `TableLayoutPanel FormatShapePage2` to something else. It worked, but after I reopen the solution the same problem is repeated with the new name instead of `FormatShapePage2`.

**My question is:**

- How can I access that mentioned dictionary to remove the duplicated value?
- What is that stack trace? I don't know where the `System.Windows.Forms.TablelayoutPanel.onlayout(LayoutEventargslevent)` methods are found.

**Note**: I don't have any errors in other parts in the solution (only rightpanel.vb), nor any errors in the code, only "Design Time Error".

Comment: What files did you reorganize immediately before this error began occurring? Note that you will probably need to delve into the partial classes that the WinForms designer autogenerates for you to see what's actually going on; that, for one thing, is where the `System.Windows.Forms` methods are being called.

Comment: @NathanTuggy

Sorry there was misunderstanding , i don't have any winForms designer in my project , i have stack trace saying : 
`System.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanels.Onlayout(layouteventsargslevents)`
I searched all the project for such a statement and i didn't find it , so i cannot delve into that place.

Concerning the files which i reorganized : 
1-unfortunately i didn't remember but i think just downloading some files from my github account
2-I cut a complete tablelayoutpanel and pasted it into another project for some reason , then i get it back again so may be this is the cause

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio and editing files in [Design] mode, you're using the WinForms designer, unless you're instead using the WPF designer or something. (Which is clearly not the case.) The generated files can be found by selecting Show All Files from the Solution Explorer toolbar, then expanding the form in question and opening the `.Designer.vb` file under it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy
Ok sorry i thought winForms only means "Windows Forms Application " , I tried to Show all the files and access the partial class of my user control and i didn't find any value which is duplicated , also i didn't find any statement relative to the stack trace .

Do you recommend that i delete that tablelayoutpanel which the program thought that it's duplicated ? 

If i deleted it , do you expect that the error will be repeated ? 

Thanks a lot for reading

Comment: It's worth trying, at least.

Comment: ok i will try doing this and i hope it works , thank you very much for reading nathan

Comment: Try to comment all the design-time code and see whether the panel is displayed at design-time in VS. Then try to uncomment the code in the line-by-line manner. Going that way you will find the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @EugeneAstafiev , but i don't support this solution , lines depend on each other ,if i comment one line others will be affected and project won't run and consequently you won't be able to determine the exact line which caused the error , plus i have so many lines and so many controls in the designer.